# How to getText() from other layout Android

Tags: java, android, fragment

How to `getText()` `AutoCompleteTextView` from other .xml ?
I already try this code:

```
    //getFragmentOrder
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    FormDataOrder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formdata_order_content_main, null);

    ti_namapic = (AutoCompleteTextView) FormDataOrder.findViewById(R.id.ti_namapic);

    String a = ti_namapic.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("Value --> "+ a);
```

If I set manually in .xml (android:text = "MyText"), 
I get that text, but if I type/input from the device screen, I don't get that value.

Edited: This is my full code.

```
public class FormDataObject extends Fragment {

AutoCompleteTextView ti_desc;
AutoCompleteTextView ti_group;

View v;
Button btn_ok;

/*--------------------------------------*/
View FormDataOrder;

AutoCompleteTextView ti_namapic;

/* =========================================================================================== */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formdata_object_content_main,container,false);


    addButtonListener();

    return v;
}

/* =========================================================================================== */
public void addButtonListener()
{

    ti_desc = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ti_desc);
    ti_group = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ti_group);

    btn_ok = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getValueFromFragmentOrder();

            System.out.println("ti_desc ----> " + ti_desc.getText());
            System.out.println("ti_group ----> " + ti_group.getText());
        }
    });
}

/* =========================================================================================== */
public void getValueFromFragmentOrder()
{
    System.out.println("getComponentFromOthersFragment ----------> RUN");

    //getFragmentOrder
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    FormDataOrder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formdata_order_content_main, null);

    ti_namapic = (AutoCompleteTextView) FormDataOrder.findViewById(R.id.ti_namapic);

    String a = ti_namapic.getText().toString();

    System.out.println("Value ----------> "+ a);
}
}
```

"getValueFromFragmentOrder();" not work, value a --> return null/empty

Comment: `but if I type/input from the device screen, I don't get that value` on which Action want to get Text which is type/input from the device screen?

Comment: you are not adding `FormDataOrder` anywhere. What you are seeing at screen is not what `FormDataOrder` is pointing to

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Text from class formdata_order, that I want get in class formdata_object.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have two instances of the `R.id.ti_namapic` view. One that is being displayed and edited and another one that is not displayed and its text remains the same. You need to get a reference to the view that is being displayed instead of creating another view.

Comment: @TommyAndroid did you solve this bro ? or still some issue left..

Comment: @ShreeKrishna nope. still some issue

Comment: do you mean some or same ? You can freely tell if another issue came...

Answer (score 0):

You are Inflating the layout, But you are not adding that View anywhere.
First Add the View And then get the Value. It will Work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do actually is get the text on `onClick` event of `btn_ok` or when ever you need it. What you are now doing now is immediately retrieving the value after calling the `findViewById` method.

**What happened here ?**

You will get only initial value that you have assigned in the EditText and store that to variable but not after when the user inputs text.

**What you need to do then ?**

**-- Modify this**

```
btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getValueFromFragmentOrder();
        String a = ti_namapic.getText().toString();

        System.out.println("a----> " + a);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 View mOrderContent;

 .....

public void getValueFromFragmentOrder()
{
    System.out.println("getComponentFromOthersFragment ----------> RUN");

    //getFragmentOrder
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout viewGroup = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    mOrderContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formdata_order_content_main, viewGroup);
    AutoCompleteTextView ti_namapic = (AutoCompleteTextView) mOrderContent.findViewById(R.id.ti_namapic);

    String a = ti_namapic.getText().toString();

    System.out.println("Value ----------> " + a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. 
It's work when I set manually in layout.xml >> android:text="Test".
but If I input from device screen, I didn't get the value ..

Comment: Yes. You're right. If you want get values at runtime you should ask the user to enter values in AutoCompleteTextView through Dialog before getting values.